# How to remove leading whitespace in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Are there any shortcuts, settings, or formatting in Visual Studio Code to remove the leading spaces where the code is written?

Usually these spaces appear when copying a certain block of code and then pasting it elsewhere, for example:

```js
var variable1 = '';
var variable2 = '';
    var variable3 = '';
    var variable4 = '';
    var variable5 = '';
```

Fixed it would look like this:

```js
var variable1 = '';
var variable2 = '';
var variable3 = '';
var variable4 = '';
var variable5 = '';
```

Comment: `Ctrl+A` and keep hold of `Shift+TAB`

Comment: Works with a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Actually CTRL + SHIFT + F combination fix indention automatically. It does not need any extension. Right click and then choose 'Format Document'. It will fix all kind of indention including your problem.

Comment: It is actually ALT + SHIFT + F in the latest versions.